# How to calculate cumulative mean in ArcGIS, ERDAS and ENVI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, erdas-imagine, envi

I'd like to get cumulative mean value from a multiband image (4 bands).

How can I do it in ArcGIS, ERDAS and ENVI?

Comment: I've placed this on hold as too broad, because as per our [Tour] there should be only one question per question, and this is effectively asking the same question for each of three products.

Answer (score 2):

[Cell Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/) in ArcGIS will calculate the mean (or statistic of choice) among multiple rasters on a cell-by-call basis.

Not sure what you mean by 'cumulative mean.' Perhaps you might be meaning the sum of the mean for each raster. If so, try the [Get Raster Properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Get_Raster_Properties/0017000000m7000000/) tool for each band and then sum them up as constants in [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) or Cell Statistics, making sure to set the Raster Analysis Properties and Extent in the Environments to same as your original rasters.